# facebook login button not working

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have 2 types of login button for facebook to automatically fetch the data from facebook. one is without using fb:login-button, which works properly. 
And another one is using fb:login-button which is not working.It goes to facebook account but does not fetch any data.
Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Some Tutorial may be helpful to you.

[PHP SDK & Graph API base Facebook Connect Tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

Comment: i wanted to fetch firstname and lastname of that user who logs in upon clicking the fb:login-button .how to do it?

Comment: You can use `FB.api`. Look at this answer. [answer1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915860/how-to-get-user-info-using-js-sdk-after-they-login-with-facebook) [answer2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131666/get-user-basic-information-using-facebook-login-button-plugin)